# Is it possible to edit a texture imported from a JSON model?

Tags: three.js

I've imported a JSON model, importing geometry and materials.

```
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

            loader.load( "alisopoli/alisopoli.js", function( geometry, materials ) {
                for ( var i = 0; i < materials.length; i ++ ) {
                    materials[ i ].side = THREE.DoubleSide;
                    materials[ i ].alphaTest = 0.75;
                    materials[ i ].overdraw = true;
                }
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
                mesh.overdraw = true;
                scene.add( mesh );
            } );
```

The model has a lot of materials (more than 30) and I need to add "THREE.nearestFilter" to each **texture** of them.
Is it possible to do something like this?

```
loader.load( "model.js", function( geometry, materials ) {
    var modelMaterials = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
    var modelTextures = modelMaterials.map
    moderTextures.minFilter = THREE.nearestFilter;
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, modelMaterials );
    scene.add( mesh );
} );
```

I want to edit the "minFilter" and "magFilter" of each texture of the model (if it is possible, of all the rendered scene).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The materials parameter that gets passed into the function is actually an array of all of your materials. What you can do is loop through that array and set the minFilter for each one, like this:

```
loader.load( "model.js", function( geometry, materials ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < materials.length; i++ ) {
        materials[i].map.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
        materials[i].map.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    }
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
    scene.add( mesh );
} );
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: There is no map in materials array. There are mapAmbient and mapDiffuse which contains texture name